# How to save user Edittext input in SQL database?

Tags: android, sql

Building an android TODO list app that save user Input in an SQL database but unable to figure out how to implement the code in an OnClick event.

here is the SQL Database code where i want to save my user input data

```
public class TaskContract {
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.aziflaj.todolist.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE = "tasks";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String COL_TASK_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TIME = "time";
}}
```

SQLDbHelper code

```
public class TaskDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public TaskDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT NOT NULL," +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME + "TEXT NOT NULL; )";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}}
```

Activity layout code

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Dialog">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title_field"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:ems="20"
        android:hint="Task Title"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/description_field"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_field"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="20"
        android:hint="Task Description"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:ems="6"
        android:id="@+id/date_field"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_field"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description_field"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/description_field"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/time_field"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date_field"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:onClick="Add_task"
        android:textColor="@color/background"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_field"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/time_field"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/time_field"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:onClick="Cancel"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/background"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/add"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have one already, you should be passing the values to a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, for example: (This has my implementation currently, so change the fields accordingly)

```
public class UserDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int database_version = 1;


    public UserDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
            String CREATE_USER_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TableInfo.TALBE_NAME + "("+ TableInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," + TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + TableInfo.USER_AUTOLOGIN + " TEXT, " + TableInfo.SESSION_ID + " TEXT, " + TableInfo.SERVER_NAME + " TEXT );";
            sdb.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           //This can be used if you'd like, it's not necessary though
    }
```

From there, you'll just need a method that can add stuff in the table, or delete when you'll need it. Use something like this:

```
public void putDataInUserTable(UserDatabase dop, String name, String pass, String autologin, String sessionId, String server) {
    SQLiteDatabase sql = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD, pass);
    cv.put(TableInfo.USER_AUTOLOGIN, autologin);
    cv.put(TableInfo.SESSION_ID, sessionId);
    cv.put(TableInfo.SERVER_NAME, server);
    long k = sql.insert(TableInfo.TALBE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

In your activity that has the code you need to get, just get the text from the edit text with:

```
EditText item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item);
String itemText = item.getText().toString();
```

And then just add it to the table by using the class that you created, example:

```
UserDatabase db = new UserDatabase(getApplicationContext());
db.putDataInUserTable(*all the parameters);
```

Comment: Did some changes to the SQLiteOpenHelper, any recommendation or tip on changes ???

Comment: You may need something to read from the database also I guess: `public Cursor getDataFromUserTable(UserDatabase dop) {
        SQLiteDatabase sql = dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD, TableInfo.USER_AUTOLOGIN, TableInfo.SESSION_ID, TableInfo.SERVER_NAME};
        Cursor cursor = sql.query(TableInfo.TALBE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }`   I can't format this, sorry. Hopefully that helps. You mostly just need to change the names and make sure you SQL statements are correct.

Comment: I added it now my app crashes when i click the Add button that uses putDataInUserTable method

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38DOncHIazs Follow this threw video 37 from the same guy, that will have all the information that you need.